# Non trivial integral with the Bose-Einstein distribution and Cosine function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Do you have any idea how to solve this integral?
$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x + {x_0}}}\left( {1 + n\left( x \right)} \right)}  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x - {x_0}}}n\left( x \right)} $$
where $n$ is the Bose-Einstein distribution:
$$n\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}}$$
and $x_0>0,m>0,b>0$.

--Notes:

Note that $n(-x)=-n(x)-1$. $n(x)$ exhibits poles in the upper half plane for purely imaginary frequencies $i{x_j}$, where ${x_j} = \frac{{2\pi }}{b}j$, $j=0,1,2,...$ are the Matsubara frequencies. In these poles:
$$n\left( x \right) \simeq \frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{{x - i{x_j}}}$$

--Other notes:

If instead of $\cos(x)$, the $\sin(x)$ function appears, the integral is trivial because we can write $\sin mx = ({e^{imx}} - {e^{ - imx}})/2i$, and make the substitution $x \to -x$ in the term ${e^{ - imx}}$. Using the property $n(-x)=-n(x)-1$ the integral can be extended from $- \infty$ to $\infty$:
$$\frac{1}{{2i}}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{imx}}}}{{x + {x_0}}}\left( {1 + n\left( x \right)} \right)}  - \frac{1}{{2i}}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{imx}}}}{{x - {x_0}}}n\left( x \right)} $$
We can take the residuum in the Matsubara frequencies, and $ \pm x_0$.
For the cosine function this trick is not valid anymore, because we can not extend the integral to $[-\infty,\infty]$. Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x + {x_0}}}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} } \right)}  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x - {x_0}}} \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} } $ is not convergent :

For $x$ tending to $0$
$$ {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x + {x_0}}}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} } \right)}  -   {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x - {x_0}}} \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} }\sim \frac{2}{b x_0}\frac{1}{x} $$
The lower bound ($x=0$) of the integral generates a logarithmic term $-\frac{2}{b x_0}\ln(0)=\infty$

Comment: Nice work as always. Are the two integrals not the same since we can relate $n(-x) =-(1+n(x))$?

Comment: The  two integrals are not the same : after remplacing $1+n(x)$ by $-n(-x)$ in the first one and changing of variable $x$ to $-x$ the bounds become ($-\infty,0$) instead of ($0,\infty$). The singularity at $x=0$ should be removable if the sign of the second integral would be $+$. The sum of the two integrals would be convergent if :$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x + {x_0}}}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} } \right)}  +\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( mx \right)}}{{x - {x_0}}} \frac{1}{{{e^{bx}} - 1}} } $. Is there a typo in the Pablo's equation ?

Comment: I am definitely not questioning the mathematics :)!! Furthermore to my previous comment, I have learnt quite a lot from your answers in the past..I just thought that you could replace $1+n(x)$ in his first integral and change from $x\to -x$? But to be honest I haven't tried.